# Can I delete .dmp and .phd files of Liberty Profile server?

Tags: websphere-liberty

In the folder `<WAS Liberty Profile root>\<profile>\usr\servers\defaultServer` there are many files named `core.*.dmp` and `heapdump.*.phd`. The size of these files is between 130 MB and 1.3 GB when my deployed app uses 4 MB.

Can I delete these files *.dmp and *.phd?

What are these files for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes, it's safe to delete them, but you should find out why they're appearing, as it could indicate that your application is not running correctly.

If your dump files were created a long time ago, or you know you were debugging an OutOfMemoryException or have been running `server javadump --include=heap,system` then go ahead and delete the files. If, however, you keep getting new dump files and don't know why then read on.

The core and heapdump files contain a snapshot of the memory of the application from a specific point in time. Usually you do this to capture the state of your application at the point where something goes wrong so that you can examine it with analysis tools and try to work out what went wrong.

For example, by default the IBM JVM will perform a dump when an OutOfMemoryException is thrown. This allows you to look at the dump file and see what's using up all the memory.

If you have a corresponding javacore file, the fourth line or so should say why the memory dump was made.

e.g. `1TISIGINFO     Dump Requested By User (00100000) Through com.ibm.jvm.Dump.javaDumpToFile` (caused by running `server javadump`)

or `1TISIGINFO     Dump Event "user" (00004000) received` (caused by running `kill -3`)

If it's a "user" event, then something's asking the JVM to create a dump. If not, and you're still not sure what's causing it, check your `jvm.options` file for any `-Xdump` options which can be used to cause the JVM to create a dump in response to certain events. More information on that [in the Knowledge Center](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.lnx.71.doc/diag/tools/dump_agents.html?lang=en).

Comment: Nice anwser. Thank you.